# ! Missing $ inserted error

Tags: errors

```
Density & 7.7 g/cm^3 \\ \hline
```

I am using this for a table and its showing me an error "! missing $ inserted" , even though my purpose of using '^' is getting fulfilled.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to be in math mode (`$`) every time you use `^`.

Comment: Or if you don't want to bother with math mode, consider using `siunitx`

Comment: Thanks @texnician , how can i modify this, i mean what part of the text should be between $...$ ?

Comment: For example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI[per-mode=symbol]{7.7}{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter}

\end{document}
` or `\SI{7.7}{g/cm^3}`

Comment: thanks @samcarter, \SI{7.7}{g/cm^3} worked perfectly fine :)

Comment: The other option would be a `g/cm$^3$` or if you do not want that `g/cm\textsuperscript{3}`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by the TeXnician in [his/her/its comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377003/missing-inserted-error#comment933805_377003) `^` only works in math mode.

To circumvent getting in this situation in the first place, I would rather use `siunitx` instead of manually writting the unit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\SI[per-mode=symbol]{7.7}{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter}

\SI{7.7}{g/cm^3}

\end{document}
```